# Highcharts Packed Bubble Automatically Pulsate & Move

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with the [Packed bubble](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/packed-bubble) chart in Highcharts and have been trying to create an effect where the individual bubbles grow and shrink plus random forces are applied so that the graph is constantly moving.

I have managed to create the base graph with the following code

```js
randomInt = 300;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'packedbubble',
    height: '100%'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    packedbubble: {
      minSize: '5%',
      maxSize: '100%',
      zMin: 0,
      zMax: 1000,
      layoutAlgorithm: {
        gravitationalConstant: 0.02,
        splitSeries: false,
        dragBetweenSeries: true,
        parentNodeLimit: true
      }
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
    name: 'Vegetable',
    data: [{
      name: 'Breakfast',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'Lunch',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'Lunch',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'Dinner',
      value: 5
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Fruit',
    data: [{
      name: 'Breakfast',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'Lunch',
      value: 5
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Grain',
    data: [{
      name: 'Breakfast',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'Breakfast',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'Lunch',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'Lunch',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'Dinner',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'Dinner',
      value: 5
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

I have attempting to set the value of each entry in series to a variable which changes over time using a simple function but the chart isn't updated to reflect these changing weightings.

To get the bubbles moving like they do when dragged I consulted the documentation [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.packedbubble) but I couldn't find any way to manually apply a force programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts has methods to dynamically update chart elements. You can use the `char.update()` method to update all series at once. You can also use the `series.setData()` method to update points for a specific series, or more precisely if you only want to update a specific point, you will achieve it by using `point.update()` method.

```js
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'packedbubble'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    packedbubble: {
      minSize: '5%',
      maxSize: '100%',
      zMin: 0,
      zMax: 50
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [5, 4, 3]
  }, {
    data: [4, 5]
  }, {
    data: [5, 5, 5, 5]
  }]
});

setTimeout(function() {
  chart.series[0].setData([5, 14, 3])
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
  chart.series[1].points[0].update({
        value: 50
    })
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s0k7fnhx/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Answer (score 0):

Try dataLabels enabled: true

```
    dataLabels: {
 enabled: true,
 format: '{point.name}',
 style: {
  color: 'black',
  textOutline: 'none',
  fontWeight: 'normal'
        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/my9f382a/12/